# How to specify types on values returned from an Angular form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In an Angular project, I have a form:

```
  constructor() {
   this.form = new FormGroup({
      description: new FormControl<string|undefined>({ value: undefined, disabled: false }),
      expectedStart: new FormControl<Date|undefined>({ value: undefined, disabled: false }),
      expectedEnd: new FormControl<Date|undefined>({ value: undefined, disabled: false }),
      priority: new FormControl<string|undefined>({ value: undefined, disabled: false })
    })
  }
```

I am destructuring the raw value returned from the form in my save function:

```
const {
  description,
  expectedStart,
  expectedEnd,
  priority,
} = this.form.getRawValue()
```

But all of those new variables are type any.

Is there a way to type them?

Comment: are you typing your form (available from angular 14)? As in, https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this :

```
const { name, age }: { name: string; age: number } = body.value
```

The best way to approach this would be to create a type or interface for that data:

```
interface Human {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const human: Human = body.value
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, I should've thought of that...